# ¿Cómo detectar evento JS cuando en un input contenga 10 dígitos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy intentando validar un input, por el momento utilizo el evento blur para que realice una función.
En dicho input debe de contener 10 dígitos, mi idea es que cuando el usuario  termine de escribir los 10 dígitos detecte la función.

Alguna idea en como podría realizarlo.
¿Es posible hacer esto?´

Este es mi codigo JS

```
$('#cec').blur(function() {
 var x = $(this).val();
 var cec = x.substr(0,4)
 enviardatos(cec);
 function enviardatos(cec){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "det.php",
        data:  {
                cec: cec
               },
        success: function(data){
            if (data.trim() == cec) {
                console.log("yes")
            }else{
                $( "#alertcec" ).show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                 $("#alertcec").fadeOut();
                 },2000);
                document.getElementById("cec").value = "";
                console.log("no");
            }
        },      
     });
    }
});
```

Este es mi HTML

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="cec" name="cec"  pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" maxlength="10"  />
```

Comment: Hola, Quieres que cuando sean 10 dígitos ejecute la función, en ese caso puedes probar con un if(x.length == 10)

Comment: Hola @kevin, Así es, justamente lo que comentas. El código que mencionas seria en lugar del blur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo comentado tu código debería quedar de la manera siguiente:

```
 $('#cec').blur(function() {//Tambien puede ser keyup que es cuando el usuario deja de presionar una tecla
 var x = $(this).val();
 var cec = x.substr(0,4)

 if(x.length == 10){ //SI CUMPLE LA LONGITUD EJECUTAMOS
    enviardatos(cec);
 }else{//opcional
    //UN MENSAJE O NO HACEMOS NADA
 }

 function enviardatos(cec){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "det.php",
        data:  {
                cec: cec
               },
        success: function(data){
            if (data.trim() == cec) {
                console.log("yes")
            }else{
                $( "#alertcec" ).show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                 $("#alertcec").fadeOut();
                 },2000);
                document.getElementById("cec").value = "";
                console.log("no");
            }
        },      
     });
    }
});
```

Comenta si es lo que buscabas.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, solo cambie blur por keyup, también funciona con keypress. Gracias. Saludos!

Comment: en efecto, también aplica pero se ejecuta un poco antes de existir el caracter